# How to use "compressor" with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to use the compressor to process a video with the following command parameters:

Compressor:

- Threshold = -21dB
- Noise floor = -35dB
- Ratio = 9:1
- Attack time = 0,20 secs
- Release time = 1,0 secs

The command should be:

```
ffmpeg -i input -af "compressor=?" output
```

How should the command look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The audio filter should be

```
-af acompressor=threshold=-21dB:ratio=9:attack=200:release=1000
```

You can supposedly express threshold as decibels but I couldn't get it to work. Fractions work, so

```
-af acompressor=threshold=0.089:ratio=9:attack=200:release=1000
```

where the threshold value is `10 to the power of (decibel value/20)`

e.g. `-21 dB` would be `10 ^ (-21/20)` = `10 ^ -1.05` = `0.08912...`

Comment: How to account for 'noise floor'?